# Tensorflow bazel build error: crt/device_runtime.h: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, tensorflow, bazel

I tried to build tensorflow from source using bazel, howerver it always failed and showed the same error as following no matter what version I used:

`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include/stddef.h:213:32: fatal error: crt/device_runtime.h: No such file or directory`.

gcc version: 4.9 / 5.4

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3

tensorflow version: r1.0 - r1.3 (with and without GPU support)

CUDA: 8.0.61

CUDNN: 5.1

LD_LIBRARY_PATH: `/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib/nvidia-375:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64`

I tried to locate this `device_runtime.h` file and I found it in the path

`/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include` but when I put export the path to `$CPATH` or `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH`, nothing changed. I would like to know what is the solution to this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is it the same error when compiling without CUDA?

Comment: Can you include more from the error?

Comment: @AllanNørgaard Yes, it's the same.

Comment: @DamienMartin-guillerez I will try to repeat this error and put more information later today, thanks.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong then -- `device_runtime.h` is related to CUDA, disabling cuda should remove this error if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I think I somehow solve this issue by doing the followings:

1. replace the `/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include` folder with the `usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/include`
2. do the `bazel clean`
3. run `./configure`.

I just it's wired that there 2 `include` folder in the cuda library.

Answer (score 0):

Provide nvcc path in makefile.

```
NVCC=/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
```

It will be able to locate the required files for complilation.